# What HDDs for HP Proliant Gen9 DL160, or suggest an alternative?

Tags: hp

I'm currently looking at a replacement for our old server, running Server 2012r2. Its struggling. I was looking at the HP DL160 Gen9 and was wondering if I can use WD Reds with it? IT's for light office use, mainly a file share, and of course AD DS. Any clue? I can only find HP Drives when I search online...

Answer (score 2):

I'd suggest using the [HP-specified disks](http://h20195.www2.hp.com/v2/GetDocument.aspx?docname=c04375607) for that machine. If you don't like the list prices, keep searching.

The right combination depends upon which storage controller you have in the server, your performance and capacity needs. E.g. the B140i only accepts SATA disks. The other storage controllers for that system can accommodate SAS disks.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Yeah, it's the b140i. Are WD se/re sata drives not suitable for this server then? It's a small office, 10 people max, it's only functions will be Domain Controller and file server.

Comment: Use the HP disks. Work with your reseller or integrator to determine the right drives for the system.